# eureka.dashboard.path doesn't seem to have any effect

Tags: spring-cloud-netflix

This could be a problem with static resource loading, but when using a custom path for the eureka dashboard, all I get is a blank page. No error, nothing in the log, just blank. Removing the custom path makes the dashboard available on "/". Here is the project to reproduce the problem:

https://github.com/knetikmedia/cluster-manager-test

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`eureka.dashboard.path` takes effect, but `/eureka` path is a default prefix used for instance for the purpose of locating static resources. Try using some different value, like /dashboard - it worked for me.